# Allow user to enter SQL select statement in web application disabling updates

Tags: sql, web, sql-injection

I need to allow users to enter SQL select statements in my web application; these select statements will be used to generate the options in a customized dropdownlist.

So I have a field on the UI where the user enters a select; how to prohibit the user of entering an insert/update/delete? I could check that the first statement word is `select` however they could enter multiple statements on the UI separated by semicolons.

Comment: What web application framework are you using? What programming language? Generally speaking you can always split the string by `;` and check each element if it contains the keyword `update`.

Comment: thanks, it's a Java+AngulaJS web application. The statements may contain strings with semicolons.

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: Bypasser's question: can you not use parameterized queries in whatever-it-is you're using to connect to the database ?

Comment: Database is Sybase IQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do the following:

- In your database create a user that only been granted SELECT privileges on the tables that you want the user to be accessible to.
- In your server, use a separate data source using the read only user from above for the queries issued from the client.

Comment: This is the only sane solution to this problem

Answer (score 2):

Trust me, a user with malicious intent will find ways to bypass your checks and inject SQL. (Especially if you are using MS-SQL Server.)

So, **do not** do this.

Write a proper user interface, no matter how complex it needs to be, and make sure that absolutely no string entered by the user ends up un-quoted and un-escaped in an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Construct your UI in such a way that the user types things like `field1, field2 from table2 where this = that`.  Prepend the word select with your programming code.

Comment: I cannot do that as I'm using codemirror for autocompleting tables/columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Connection.setReadonly(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setReadOnly-boolean-) method to enable read-only transactions. But I would use that only if user input is trusted and we need to prevent an accidental change of data.